# modulo operation on uuid to determine shard_id

Tags: database, postgresql, math, uuid, sharding

We have Postgresql database and we are doing some sharding there. Also we are doing READ load-balancing. To do that, first we check on which shard data is located.

We are getting shard id based on this formula:

```
entry_id % num_of_shards = shard_id
```

and it works good. Currently we have auto increment ids (int).

We want to switch to uuid v4. What formula will be in case of uuid to determine shard_id?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The simplest is to turn the shard_id into a text value. If you want 16 shards then use only the first char from the uuid. For 256 shards use the first 2 chars and so on.

```
select substring(uuid_generate_v4()::text from 1 for 2) as shard_id;
 shard_id 
----------
 c6
```

For just two shards get the least significant bit of the first char:

```
select
    substring(
        ('x' || substring(uuid_generate_v4()::text from 1 for 1))::bit(4) 
        from 4 for 1
    ) as shard_id
;
 shard_id 
----------
 0
```

For four shards get 2 bits (`from 3 for 2`) and so on. Or for an integer as commented:

```
select 
    (
        'x' || substring(uuid_generate_v4()::text from 1 for 1)
    )::bit(4)::int % 2 as shard_id
```

Comment: Nice. If I have just two shards, then I would do something like ``select substring(uuid_generate_v4()::text from 1 for 2)::integer % 2;``

This is wrong syntax, but you know what I mean. Or you have better idea how to handle less than 16 shards?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the UUIDs just to avoid showing consecutive IDs to users? In that case, keep the serial-style ID and add the UUID in addition to it (simply add a UNIQUE index on it). That way you can keep using module and you can also use the simple numeric ID e.g. on foreign keys.

If you use the UUIDs because you need globally unique IDs (since sequences are always "local") you'll have to to use *some* way to convert the UUID to a number.

The easiest way would probably be taking the a few digits of the UUID and converting them to a number.

Comment: It is second case. We want to use postgresql 9.5 sharding feature with foreign tables, to be able to scale horizontally.